# Podio items to excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, podio

I need to have a vba macro that downloads data from my Podio app to an excel sheet. Right now I am running a code I found on Podio community website, which I am pasting below:

```
Dim winHttpReq As Object
Dim access_token As String

Function ProjectsFromPodio()

Dim result As String
Dim postData As String
Dim myURL As String
Dim token_pos As Long

'Initialisierung
Set winHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
myURL = "https://api.podio.com/oauth/token"

postData = "grant_type=app&app_id=ABC&app_token=DEF&client_id=GHI&client_secret=JKL"

If winHttpReq.Open("POST", myURL, False) = S_OK Then
    'MsgBox ("Open successfull")
End If
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
winHttpReq.Send (postData)

result = winHttpReq.responseText
token_pos = InStr(result, "access_token")
access_token = Mid(result, token_pos + 15)
token_pos = InStr(access_token, Chr(34)) - 1
access_token = Mid(access_token, 1, token_pos)

OAuthAppAuthorization = result
'MsgBox (OAuthAppAuthorization)

Set winHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
myURL = "https://api.podio.com/item/app/XYZ"
winHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "OAuth2 " & access_token
winHttpReq.Send
result = winHttpReq.responseText
'MsgBox (result)
End Function
```

This works nice, data is downloaded and I can use it. My question is how to download this data in CSV format, rather than JSON? Is it possible?

If it is not possible, how can I parse it to a sheet in a smart way?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Your question's answer really lies in the services that the Podio API supports, not the VBA code above. You'd have to research potential formatting options for your POST/GET request so that the Podio server can format your data as CSV coming back to you. If JSON is the only option and you really, really need the data in CSV, you'll have to write a converter yourself. There is no clear indication of the JSON format or what you need in CSV in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You may send the `POST` request to `/item/app/{app_id}/export/{exporter}`which creates a batch for exporting the items. 
Here you can export the items as **xls** and **xlsx** formats.

Your `myURL` must be like,

```
myURL = "https://api.podio.com/item/app/XYZ/export/xls"
```

You will get a batch_id as a result of this request.

Then make a `GET` call to `/batch/{batch_id}` to get the `status` of the batch. You can download the output xls file by making a `GET` request to `/file/{file_id}` using the `podio_file_id` from the batch response.

**References**

- [Podio - Export Items](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/export-items-4235696)
- [Podio - Get Batch](https://developers.podio.com/doc/batch/get-batch-6144225)
- [Podio - Get File](https://developers.podio.com/doc/files/get-file-22451)